# Elasticsearch Must on list object

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I am using Elastic 6.0 .My kibana query is as below

```
  "bool": {
       "must": [
          {
           "match": {
             "relationships.relation": {
               "query": "spouse"
            }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "relationships.first_name": {
          "query": "james"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "relationships.last_name": {
          "query": "smith"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which gives me results as

```
    1.    "relationships": [
        {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Heafner",
          "relation": "Father"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Mary",
          "last_name": "Dellinger",
          "relation": "Mother"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "James S.",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "relation": "Spouse"
        }
      ]

    2. "relationships": [
        {
          "first_name": "James",
          "last_name": "Hickey",
          "relation": "Father"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Mary",
          "last_name": "Raftery",
          "relation": "Mother"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Richard",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "relation": "Spouse"
        }
      ]
```

I want only 1st result as it contains exact match based on my query
             {
                "first_name": "James S.",
                 "last_name": "Smith",
                "relation": "Spouse"
              }
  I have tried term query but it is giving same results as above. Any suggestion 
  would be of much help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have `relationships` mapped as an [`object` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html). For this to work as you expect, `relationships` needs to be mapped as a [`nested` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and you should use [`nested` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to query fields of the *nested* objects.

Comment: Is there any other option as above solution means I need to change existing mapping

Comment: No other option I'm afraid. The easiest way to remedy may be to use the Reindex API to reindex documents into a new index that has the `nested` mapping for `relationships` configured.